# Use local class in Application Settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

A while back, I used [this answer exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194818/9970) to store a StringDictionary in my Application Settings in a C# 4.0 application. Upon upgrading it to C# 4.7.2, the entry using this class will no longer be generated into Settings.Designer.cs and the Settings gui won't let me select the class.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39494795/9970), I've added `[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]` and a parameter-less constructor, to no avail.

I also tried bypassing the designer and changing the entry in Settings.settings from `<SerializableStringDictionary>` to `<BBot.SerializableStringDictionary>`.

I know there's several ways to skin this cat, so I'm mostly curious what changed to cause it to be rejected now.

Comment: Well, I just solved it by reverting the changed to the generated file, bringing back the code it had generated. Its sticking around through a rebuild.

Comment: However, my entry still no longer appears in the Settings UI, so any possible future changes would likely necessitate more manual intervention