# Is there any way to add an class object as a Setting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I would like to save an entire class in the settings (Visual Studio 2015):

[image: screenshot]

I tried [How do I save/serialize a custom class to the settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321248/how-do-i-save-serialize-a-custom-class-to-the-settings-file)
but was unable to reproduce the result.

Comment: You need to explain **why** you couldn't reproduce the result and what the **deficit** is in the answer you linked to for this to be a valid question.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but was unable to find ReportSetting in the settings. Is there any way to Save an entire class object in the Visual Studio Settings?

Comment: It says that you have to type it, as it will not show up...